# Common syntax to specific stdout as "output file"

Tags: shell

I have a mainly unixoid software that usually writes to a file that is specified as a parameter.

Now I want to add the ability to write to stdout instead. But to write to a file should still be the standard behavior.

I think I saw shell commands like

```
command --outfile -
```

or

```
command -
```

Is that a common practise? Unfortunately I do not recall the commands that worked like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common method is to write to stdout when the last argument in the parameter list is a hyphen (or in some cases, a double-hyphen).

If you are creating a program, you can go an extra step and use an explicit `-stdout` parameter for printing to standard output.  Since the `-` syntax is not an official standard, I would suggest that it is better to err on the side of readability.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen is used in various *nix commands to indicate either stdin or stdout, depending on what context it's used in. It is *fairly* common but by no means universal, so you should check the documentation for a specific command before using it.

Comment: <sarcasm>Reading the documentation is so boring. For example "-v" means always verbose. pkill is a good example for that</sarcasm>

Answer (score 1):

Common practice (an example is gzip) is to write to stdout if either a file is not specified (assuming you can determine that) or a hyphen is given as the last option.